# No horizontal line displayed between options menu item

Tags: android, line, android-menu

I implemented an options menu in my application using `menu.xml`. And the menu is displayed in two rows. But there is no line separator horizontally between these rows of menuItems. But other applications shows menu items with line separator by default.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
      <item android:id="@+id/scan"
            android:icon="@drawable/scan"
            android:title="Scan" />

      <item android:id="@+id/imei"
            android:icon="@drawable/imei"
            android:title="IMEI" />

      <item android:id="@+id/serno"
            android:icon="@drawable/serno"
            android:title="SerialNo" />

      <item android:id="@+id/update"
            android:icon="@drawable/update"
            android:title="Updates" />

      <item android:id="@+id/about"
            android:icon="@drawable/about"
            android:title="About" /> 

      <item android:id="@+id/exit"
            android:icon="@drawable/exit"
            android:title="Exit" />
</menu>
```

Am I missing something? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @AleksG We submitted our edits at the same time. I didn't deliberately override your edit, no offense intended.

Comment: @AleksG thanks.. Hav any answers?

Comment: anyt updates on this